# Helm chart restart pods when configmap changes

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to restart the pods when there is a confimap or secret change. I have tried the same piece of code as described in: https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/charts_tips_and_tricks.md#automatically-roll-deployments-when-configmaps-or-secrets-change
However, after updating the configmap, my pod does not get restarted. Would you have any idea what could has been done wrong here?

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ template "app.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    app: {{ template "app.name" . }}
    {{- include "global_labels" . | indent 4 }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ template "app.name" . }}
      release: {{ .Release.Name }}
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        checksum/config: {{ include (print $.Template.BasePath "/configmap.yml") . | sha256sum }}
        checksum/secret: {{ include (print $.Template.BasePath "/secret.yml") . | sha256sum }}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Neither Helm nor Kubernetes provide a specific rolling update for a ConfigMap change. The workaround has been for a while is to just patch the deployment which triggers the rolling update:

```
kubectl patch deployment your-deployment -n your-namespace -p '{"spec":{"template":{"metadata":{"annotations":{"date":"$(date)"}}}}}'
```

And you can see the status:

```
kubectl rollout status deployment your-deployment
```

Note this works on a nix machine. This is until this [feature](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/13488) is added.

*Update 05/05/2021*

Helm and `kubectl` provide this now:

Helm: https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#automatically-roll-deployments

kubectl: `kubectl rollout restart deploy WORKLOAD_NAME`

Comment: Thank you very much. Even if this is not an "out of the box" feature, isn't Helm supposed to handle this situation?

Comment: Yes, it should but my guess is that the feature is not quite there in K8s so it might not have been addressed in Helm either.

Comment: … the template in the question already contains almost the same change as you do with the patch, so how does doing it manually help?

Comment: But the change in the question is a ConfigMap, and that doesn't automatically trigger an update as of today.  If it's another change like the date, it will trigger the update. You could also trigger it with a helm update but not a ConfigMap change.

Comment: @Rico The JSON argument here doesn't quite work (I think Stack Overflow stripped the grave accents you originally used for command substitution).  Given a shell such as bash, this works (tested on Mac and Ubuntu): `'{"spec":{"template":{"metadata":{"annotations":{"date": '$(date +'%s')' }}}}}'` giving valid JSON with date value.

Comment: You can now run `kubectl rollout restart deploy WORKLOAD_NAME`

Comment: Thanks for the info. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 18):

https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#automatically-roll-deployments Helm3 has this feature now. deployments are rolled out when there is change in configmap template file.

Comment: I feel this should be the accepted answer nowadays. Much cleaner and more direct than calling patch by hand.

Comment: this doesn't work for me, the annotation changes but the daemonset won't restart

Answer (score 11):

it worked for me, below is the code snippet from my deployment.yaml file, make sure your configmap and secret yaml file are same as what referred in the annotations:

```
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        checksum/config: {{ include (print $.Template.BasePath "/my-configmap.yaml") . | sha256sum }}
        checksum/secret: {{ include (print $.Template.BasePath "/my-secret.yaml") . | sha256sum }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I deployed pod with configmap with this feature https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#automatically-roll-deployments.
When I edited the configmap at runtime , it didn't trigger the roll-deployment.

Comment: If you edit configurations yourself, during runtime, in between Helm applies, ... then this is perfectly normal